# DOM traversing and same origin policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

i'm currently working on a DOM accessing it's nodes.then i ran into an iframe,i tried accessing the node but i keep getting undefined.the ifram is protected by same origin policy so i tried using CORS,get a response then navigate it but i keep getting undefined........
    $body = document.body;

```
$body.children[3];
$yo = $body.children[3];
$yo.children[0];
$next = $yo.children[0];
$next.children[3];
$plus = $next.children[3];
$plus.children[0];
$star = $plus.children[0];
$star.children[0];
$staragain = $star.children[0];
$staragain.children[1];
$nextstar = $staragain.children[1];
$nextstar.children[1];
$afternext = $nextstar.children[1];
```

//accesses the DOM up to the iframe

```
var CORSObject = null;
if(typeof(XMLHttpRequest) != "undefined")
{
CORSObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
CORSObject.withCredentials = true;
}
else if(typeof(XDomainRequest) != "undefined")
{
//For IE XDomainRequest is required for CORS request
CORSObject = new XDomainRequest();
//XDomainRequest doesn't support sending and receiving of cookies.
}
else
{
CORSObject = null;
}

if(CORSObject != null)
{
/*
    All browsers set Origin Header while sending an AJAX Request
    Some don't include this header if the AJAX request is for same
domain.
*/

CORSObject.open("GET", "https://www.com/ajaxData.php");

CORSObject.onload = function() {alert(CORSObject.responseText);};
CORSObject.onerror = function() {alert("There was an error")};

CORSObject.send();
}
//process cors response
CORSObject.onload = function() {
var responseText = CORSObject.responseText;
console.log(responseText);
// process the response.
};

CORSObject.onerror = function() {
console.log('There was an error!');
};
//to bypass same origin policy
```

then i ran the code again but the iframe keeps returning undefined.....

how do i go about this,to access the iframe?

Comment: The AJAX request has nothing to do with the iframe. You can't access the contents of an iframe from a different domain.

Comment: is there no way around this?

Comment: The way to get around CORS is by using a proxy script on your server.

Comment: can you please show me how sir,it will be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy

Comment: thank you sir i got it......one more question sir,can i run it in firebug?

Comment: Sorry, don't know enough about firebug. Try it and see.

Comment: thanks for the help sir...will get back to you when i'm through with it sir.

Comment: sorry to disturb you,but how do i go about this? p.s i run a windows10.

Comment: i dont know how to use it.....please put me through.thanks...you're the best plus handsome.

Comment: Download the script, edit the configuration variables, and install it on your webserver. Assuming you have PHP, it should just work. If any of this is over your head, I can't teach you in this forum.

Comment: if i want learn,where can you teach me?

Comment: There are many tutorials on PHP, you're on your own.

Comment: Thank you barman.....you like that?